# Reading json data from a file in d3.js not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js

This is a d3 code that generates a line graph from data.tsv file. However I want to input data in form of json. So what will be changes required here. There is a line marked with *'s .I have changed tsv to json but the code is not working.

```
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y");
var  x=12;
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {    ///////*****/////
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {   return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

function type(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Comment: What happened when you made the change to .json?  You can print out the error on the console.  If the tsv form is not working either, you are probably dealing with cross-origin request issue.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question if you don't show us the JSON you hope to use and the code you are using to process that JSON.  Right now you are showing us d3 sample code that works just fine...

Comment: What happen to make you cancel my accepted answer? Did my solution stop to work? And then you edited your question and deleted all your comments. This is not how SO works. If you have another problem, write another question.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your questions; once posted your question together with any answers become a whole, and destroying part of that whole damages the answers too. That's not fair to the people that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check if your JSON structure correctly matches the data in your TSV or CSV. For instance, suppose that this is your CSV:

```
foo, bar
4, 5
12, 2
3, 61
```

Your JSON should be like this:

```
[
 { 
   "foo": 4,
   "bar": 5
 },
 { 
   "foo": 12,
   "bar": 2
 },
 { 
   "foo": 3,
   "bar": 61
 }
]
```

That is, an array of objects. Sometimes, in very big and complex JSONs, it's easy to forget a comma or a brace. I use codebeautify to check:

http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

And, then, just change `d3.tsv` for `d3.json`:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data){
    console.log(data); //just to check if it's all right
    //the rest of your code
});
```

NOTE: Contrary to `d3.csv` and `d3.tsv`, you cannot provide an accessor function to `d3.json`.

Comment: You cannot use an accessor with JSON, only with CSV and TSV (check here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests). The accessor is the `type` in `("data.json", type, function(error, data)`. Remove that and parse the dates after the JSON is loaded, and you'll see that it works.

Comment: Because it's not only removing the `type`. Now, you'll have to parse the dates.

Comment: Beautiful. I see you are new at SO, so, let me tell you that when an answer solves the problem, please accept it, not only because the RP but for other people to know that it solved the problem. Cheers.